# egrep regular expression + print specific names from files with egrep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to print only the following Linux machines names from `/tmp/file.txt`

while xx is number as 01 - 999

```
Linux_serverXX
Linux_agentXX
Linux_masterXX
```

The file is

```
more /tmp/file.txt

Linux_server01
Linux_server02
Linux_server03
Linux_main01
Linux_main02
Linux_agent01
Linux_agent02
Linux_agent03
Linux_domain_server01
Linux_master01
Linux_master02
Linux_master02
Linux_alert01
Linux_alert02
```

So we did that

```
egrep "Linux_server[[:digit:]]|Linux_agent[[:digit:]]|Linux_master[[:digit:]]" /tmp/file
```

is it good enough approach to exclude the names that we want?

Comment: `grep -E 'Linux_(server|agent|master)[[:digit:]]' file` might be better

Comment: by using "^" its will machine only if names in the beginning of file , so I prefer not use it

Comment: If the matches are not actually representing the whole line, use `grep -Eo 'Linux_(server|agent|master)[0-9]+' /tmp/file`

Comment: You have put XX in the requirements but some of entries may have XXX. Are you saying that you want to discount these entries? or just print the first two digit of the 3 digits I.e. Linux_server901 being Linux_server90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -Eo 'Linux_(server|agent|master)[[:digit:]]{2,3}' file
```

As you have specified that the number can range from 01-999 I would be stricter with the number matching and specify digits with a length range of 2 to 3.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'match($0,/Linux_(server|agent|master)[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

OR use following in case you have multiple matches on a single line this could help then:

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/Linux_(server|agent|master)[0-9]+/)){
    print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                     ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  while(match($0,/Linux_(server|agent|master)[0-9]+/)){   ##using while loop which will run till a match of regex is found in match function.
    print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)                       ##Printing sub string from RSTART till RLENGTH.
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)                          ##Saving rest of line(without matched part above) in current line itself.
  }
}
'  Input_file                                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```